# Difference between join and prefetch in DBIx::Class

Tags: join, dbix-class, prefetch, perl

Please explain in details the difference between `join` and `prefetch` in `DBIx::Class`.

`joins` maps to `JOIN` in SQL, right?

`prefetch` makes to read all data from related tables, right?

But it seems for me that in the case of a `has_a` relationship to a table, joining and prefetching this table do exactly the same thing, add an SQL `JOIN`. Right? Is there any difference between `join` and `prefetch` for `has_a` relationships?

So when to use either (especially for `has_a` relationships)?

Answer (score 3):

Prefetch is sugar for join + select and populates the cache with related result objects so no SQL query is triggered when you call the relationship accessor method.

Comment: You haven't answered my question: Is there any difference between `join` and `prefetch` when the relevant relation is `has_a`? You say that `prefetch` is "sugar" for join. So both produce the same `JOIN`, right? Then what is the difference?

Comment: `join` only adds the `JOIN` to the select, so you can use the fields in the joined table in `where` , but if you then try to use the relationship accessor to access fields in a joined table, it will make another query to get that data.   With `prefetch`, the fields from the joined table will added to the `SELECT` and the relationship accessor will be able to use those, and not have to make another query